# mvc bool value in class attribute on element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following:

```
var selected = true;
<span class="selected-@selected">text</span>
```

Depending on the value of selected, I am expected the following output:

```
<span class="selected-True">text</span>
<span class="selected-False">text</span>
```

But I get:

```
<span class="selected-class">text</span>
<span class="selected-">text</span>
```

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think it's because of how razor is being smart in cases when you want to do things like

`<input type="checkbox" checked="@true" />`

which becomes

`<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />`

that's why in your case, the value of the property became `class`

to fix this you could try

`<span class="selected-@selected.ToString()">text</span>`